# How can I see only a part of whole radar graph in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, graph

I am trying to plot 180 degree lidar data on radar graph using matplotlib. Code is like

```
import sys
import os
import struct
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time
import math

ax = plt.subplot(111, polar=True)
plt.ylim(0,255)

def animate():
    ax.clear()
    ax.plot(xar, lidarData, linewidth=1, linestyle='solid')
    plt.pause(0.0001)

plt.ion()
plt.show(block=False)
```

where xar is angles -90 to 90 (plot expects rad). Since I am using only upper half of the graph, how do I make it display only half of the circle? so that I can see data clearly.

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Your posted code fails on undefined symbols.  You've neglected the required `import` statements.

Comment: thank you for pointing that out. Just updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ax.set_thetamax(180)` before `plt.show()`. You can also `ax.set_thetamin()` if you don't want it to start from 0.

EDIT : Python 3.9.2 code as required by OP.

```py
import sys
import os
import struct
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time
import math

ax = plt.subplot(111, polar=True)
plt.ylim(0,255)

def animate():
    ax.clear()
    ax.plot(xar, lidarData, linewidth=1, linestyle='solid')
    plt.pause(0.0001)

plt.ion()
ax.set_thetamax(180)
    
plt.show(block=False)
```

Result:
[image]

Of course, it's a blank graph as I don't have lidarData.

Comment: I tried that but it is not cutting the graph circle into section (like a piece of pie).

Comment: I copy pasted your code & added just that one line and I got upper semi-circle. Can't reproduce your error.

Comment: are you using python 3 or 2? Can you share your code?

Comment: If it still doesn't works, maybe share your `xar` and `lidarData`?

Comment: i am using 3.7.3 . That is weird. Let me try with 3.9.2

Comment: I don't think that should be an issue, you can try thoug,

Comment: i wrote this in IDLE, not in notebook.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230493/discussion-between-shivam-chauhan-and-deep).